# Is there a way to identify the Apps names?

Tags: java, android, autofill

I'm developing a service with Auto-filling on third-party Apps forms. Now I need to know if there's a way to identify the third-party App name.

The reason for this is that I have a working web extension which already has the form information to be filled so now I want to also fill with these data if the user opens the same company Apps like for example a user opens Facebook or Messanger and when it show form my service will check if this user has already stored any data for Facebook or when the data is from the App and if the user let me save it for later user on other devices and platforms.

Is it possible? I saw as if the overly service or filling service just generalize and I'm not sure if I can group by App names based on the App the data was taken from.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot detect an App launch in Android.
However, you can get the list of currently open apps using [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) class as shown below:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningAppProcessesList = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

Then check if the app you are looking for is on the list.

```
int size = runningAppProcessesList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
{
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo = runningAppProcessesList.get(i);
 
    if(processInfo.processName.equals(APPNAME)) {
       //user has this app
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant was to be able to identify the foreground App. Let me continue with the Facebook example as above. Let say a user had been using my extension to login to his/her Facebook account on the computer web browser, now the user had just got a new phone and had installed Facebook but has not yet logged in to it because the user don't want to type the information but want my Auto-fill service to fill it automatically. Now the question is how can I identify that the App that is open and has a login form is Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

The above code snippet will work for the background apps.
To check if the app is running in the foreground, use the following code:

```
public static boolean isForeground(Context context, String myPackage){
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = manager.getRunningTasks(1); 

    ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
    if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage)) {
        return true;
    }       
    return false;
}
```

You just need to know the package name of the desired app.
And since you wanna know about the auto-filling of the form, you may use [Autofill Service in Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-services).